# Spock test showing groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have the following spock test. I am first going to the login page, and then I am clicking the login button without entering an email and password to verify the error message. I will add other steps later such as email but no password and email with incorrect password, but I first need to get this test to work.

```
package loginPageTests

import Pages.loginPage
import geb.Page
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class invalidLoginSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Go to login page"() {
        when:
        Page loginPage = to loginPage
        waitFor { loginPage.loginButton.isDisplayed() }

        then:
        at loginPage
    }

    def "Try to log in without email or password"() {
        when:
        loginPage.loginButton.click()

        then:
        at loginPage
        assert loginPage.loginError.text() == "Please enter your email and password."
    }
}
```

And the following page object

```
package Pages

import geb.Page

class loginPage extends Page {
    static url = 'login/'
    static at = { title == "Login to TB"}
    static content = {
        loginButton {$("#loginButton")}
        loginError(wait:true) {$("#loginError")}
    }
}
```

The first method runs successfully, but I get this error when the second method tries to run

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: loginButton
>   for class: Pages.loginPage

the property loginButton is in the loginPage page object, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring.

Comment: Please use normal camel case for classes, e.g. `LoginPage` and `InvalidLoginSpec`. You might want to look into `@Stepwise` for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are interacting with the page is non-idiomatic but to answer the question asked...

You have defined `loginPage` as a local variable inside of the first test method and then tried to reference it inside of the second test method where it is out of scope.